# Folder invisible in file manager, but shows up in terminal with Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I'm running Ubuntu 13.04 64-bit and I have a directory with 2 folders and a file in it. The problem is that only one of these folders is actually visible in the visual file manager:

[image]

You can see that the `bin` folder does exist and I have rights to access it, however. I noticed this happening before to some random other directories. What could be causing this?

Comment: I solved the problem by pressing F5. I'll leave the question open in case of any other insights.

Comment: @terdon Alright, will do.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I solved this problem by pressing `F5` in the file manager with the directory open.

Comment: I just signed up on stackexchange just to upvote this answer...gr8